# Electronic Signature & Joomla

Tags: development

I am using Joomla 3 and need to create some online forms for a client (I am using the RSFormPro extension which is great).

However one feature that this extension does not include is the ability for the applicant to add their signature. Does anybody know how I could incorporate such a feature?

Ideally, I would like to use something like https://github.com/brinley/jSignature

If anybody has done this or has experience in jSignature please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know RS Form provides the ability to add custom code and scripts to your forms. 
Regarding JSignature, I didn't read all the API info from the link you posted, so I can't be sure how it works and its requirements.

Having said that, here is how I would approach this. 
First of course I would read the documentation to fully understand how everything works and what I can do with it.

Then, I would experiment on the implementation, by following the main instructions on how to set up JSignature in any other page. - At the end, everything comes down to the basics (html, js, php etc).
So, set up the form, create the elements for JSignature and give them the required ids. I saw that it asks for a div element, but it is possible that it could work with other elements as well.

Of course, we need to link the JSignature scripts to the form. If the div is essential for the script, then we could add that special RS Form element, that is used to display static text and try to add the desired markup in there. It could be handy, to set the Form layout creation to manual, and build the form mark-up the way we need it.

However, at the moment, I have no idea at all about how all this will work to store the signature in the database, or give us the ability to catch the signature from each submission in any other way.

Just a guess: Maybe we could have a hidden file field in RS Form, and with a few bits of code, using the script's API and the RS Form ability to save in the database, we could get close to that.

Also, I would get in touch with the RS Form developers and ask for their input. It could be possible that they like the idea and implement such a feature in the coming releases.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this one?

Comment: I did thanks and I managed to get it working on a dev site, there was so much coding to make it work! Had I known this I probably would have created a stand alone form and not used RSForms at all. The client eventually decided not to go with it! Your advice above was very useful and I learnt a lot from the experiement, thanks. p.s I did contact the developers.. still awaiting a reply!

Answer (score 0):

[Breezing forms](https://crosstec.org/en/downloads/breezingforms-for-joomla.html) has this feature built in and is a Joomla! component. It's REALLY powerful.

Here's a demo: https://crosstec.org/breezingformsdemo/index.php/breezingforms-demos/bootstrap-based-forms/new-digital-signatures.html

You may also want to check this post which suggests a different (paid) service.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24265531/electronic-signature-joomla